# Iterating through constructor's arguments

Tags: python, constructor, arguments

I often find myself writing class constructors like this:

```
class foo:
    def __init__(self, arg1, arg2, arg3):
        self.arg1 = arg1
        self.arg2 = arg2
        self.arg3 = arg3
```

This can obviously become a pain if the number of arguments (and class attributes) gets high. I'm looking for the most pythonic way to loop through the constructor's arguments list and assign attributes accordingly. I'm working with Python 2.7, so ideally I'm looking for help with that version.

Comment: This is it. If you have too much arguments in any function, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: Easy for you to say :) I have to manipulate data extracted from a 20+ column CSV file. I need ways to construct objects from multiple sources. The point is, depending on the requirements, you could need a high amount of arguments.

Comment: Make it one, a list. You can then zip it with a list of keywords to form a dict, if you want easier access.

Comment: @Cat Plus Plus. I'm not sure that's accurate. The Hitchhiker's Guide to Python says that too heavy a dependence on global (or self) variables to control methods is a sign of bad structure. AKA "Heavy usage of global state or context: instead of explicitly passing (height, width, type, wood) to each other..." http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/structure/

Comment: @BurningKrome This quote has nothing to do with this. Also instance state is not global state, I have no idea how you inferred "`self` is bad" from "don't use global state".

Comment: Well...if you're not passing a variable explicitly into the function's namespace, then you're using variables outside the namespace. "self.var" is a variable outside the functions namespace. "self.var" and "global var" are the same concepts discussed in that paragraph...Ie one should not allow your functions to depend on global (outside the namespace) variables (including presumably (self.variable) because they can change outside the namespace in unexpected ways.

Comment: Personally, I tend to agree with you - that passing all the variables in and out seems unnecessary and cumbersome. Nonetheless, I do think the best practices (in this case) makes no distinction between "global" vars and "self" vars.

Comment: I'm mostly interested in better understanding the style guides. This is what the paragraph says, "Heavy usage of global state or context: instead of explicitly passing (height, width, type, wood) to each other, Table and Carpenter rely on global variables that can be modified and are modified on the fly by different agents. You need to scrutinize all access to these global variables to understand why a rectangular table became a square, and discover that remote template code is also modifying this context, messing with table dimensions."

Comment: It would be nice if StackOverflow comments were used to address the question, instead of just saying 'you're doing it wrong'

Comment: From python >= 3.7 you can use the dataclass decorator; added an answer below

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The most Pythonic way is what you've already written. If you are happy to require named arguments, you could do this:

```
class foo:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        vars(self).update(kwargs)
```

Comment: I would suggest
    `vars(self).update(kwargs)`
As slightly easier to read. YMMV.

Comment: @TimS1234: Thanks for the suggestion. You learn something new every day.

Answer (score 11):

Provided answers rely on `*vargs` and `**kargs` arguments, which might not be convenient at all if you want to restrict to a specific set of arguments with specific names: you'll have to do all the checking by hand.

Here's a decorator that stores the provided arguments of a method in its bound instance as attributes with their respective names.

```
import inspect
import functools

def store_args(method):
    """Stores provided method args as instance attributes."""
    argspec = inspect.getargspec(method)
    defaults = dict(zip( argspec.args[-len(argspec.defaults):], argspec.defaults ))
    arg_names = argspec.args[1:]
    @functools.wraps(method)
    def wrapper(*positional_args, **keyword_args):
        self = positional_args[0]
        # Get default arg values
        args = defaults.copy()
        # Add provided arg values
        list(map( args.update, ( zip(arg_names, positional_args[1:]), keyword_args.items() ) ))
        # Store values in instance as attributes
        self.__dict__.update(args)
        return method(*positional_args, **keyword_args)

    return wrapper
```

You can then use it like this:

```
class A:
    @store_args
    def __init__(self, a, b, c=3, d=4, e=5):
        pass

a = A(1,2)
print(a.a, a.b, a.c, a.d, a.e)
```

Result will be `1 2 3 4 5` on Python3.x or `(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)` on Python2.x

Comment: If you add this line `if not argspec.defaults is None` you don't need to end with default values for your arguments. The else statement should be `defaults = {}`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that both for positional and for keyword arguments:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        for arg in args:
            print arg
        for kwarg in kwargs:
            print kwarg
```

`*` packs positional arguments into a tuple and `**` keyword arguments into a dictionary:

```
foo = Foo(1, 2, 3, a=4, b=5, c=6) // args = (1, 2, 3), kwargs = {'a' : 4, ...}
```

Comment: You can also even assign from positional arguments this way, so long as they are strings, like `for arg in args: setattr(self, arg, arg)`

Comment: i guess positional arguments do not work in his case - he needs to assign an attribute of the object. how do you do this not knowing attribute's name?

Comment: @agf, what the point of having attributes which have a string value equal to their names?

Comment: Beats me, but if you look at the question, that's what he asked (though doubtfully what he meant), so I provided the answer.

Comment: Positional arguments can be used to set instance attributes as long as there is an implicit order on these attributes (see e.g. the range function). Not that I would recommend this, though. Keyword arguments are the right choice here.

Comment: @agf: Not exactly what I asked. If you read carefully the question, you'll notice that it's the function definition, not the function call that I showed. Something like that: 

def __init__(self,name): 
   self.name = name

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
class foo:
    def __init__(self, arg1, arg2, arg3):
        for _prop in dir():
            setattr(self, _prop, locals()[_prop])
```

This uses the builtin python dir function to iterate over *all* local variables.
It has a minor side effect of creating an extraneous self reference but you could filter that if you really wanted.
Also if you were to declare any other locals before the dir() call, they would get added as constructed object's attributes as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
class foo:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        for arg_name, arg_value in kwargs.items():
            setattr(self, arg_name, arg_value)
```

This requires arguments to be named:

```
obj = foo(arg1 = 1, arg2 = 2)
```

Comment: `dict.iteritems()` or `dict.viewitems()` if you don't want to make a copy.

Answer (score 1):

What about iterating over the explicit variable names?

I.e.

```
class foo:
    def __init__(self, arg1, arg2, arg3):
        for arg_name in 'arg1,arg2,arg3'.split(','):
            setattr(self, arg_name, locals()[arg_name])

f = foo(5,'six', 7)
```

Resulting with

```
print vars(f)

{'arg1': 5, 'arg2': 'six', 'arg3': 7}
```

My suggestion is similar to @peepsalot, except it's more explicit and doesn't use `dir()`, which according to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#dir)

> its detailed behavior may change across releases

Answer (score 0):

As others have noted, you should probably stick to your original 'pythonic' method in most cases.

However, if you really want to go the whole nine yards, here's some code that neatly deals with args, keyword args if desired, and avoids boilerplate repetition:

```
def convert_all_args_to_attribs(self, class_locals):
    class_locals.pop('self')
    if 'kwargs' in class_locals:
        vars(self).update(class_locals.pop('kwargs'))
    vars(self).update(class_locals)

class FooCls:
    def __init__(self, foo, bar):
        convert_all_args_to_attribs(self, locals())

class FooClsWithKeywords:
    def __init__(self, foo, bar, **kwargs):
        convert_all_args_to_attribs(self, locals())

f1 = FooCls(1,2)
f2 = FooClsWithKeywords(3,4, cheese='stilton')


print vars(f1) #{'foo': 1, 'bar': 2}
print vars(f2) #{'cheese': 'stilton', 'foo': 3, 'bar': 4}
```

Answer (score 0):

For python >= 3.7 take a look at the [@dataclass](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) class decorator.
Among other things, it handles your `__init__` boilerplate coding problem.

From the [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html):

```
@dataclass
class InventoryItem:
    name: str
    unit_price: float
    quantity_on_hand: int = 0
```

Will automatically add an `__init__` like that:

```
def __init__(self, name: str, unit_price: float, quantity_on_hand: int=0):
    self.name = name
    self.unit_price = unit_price
    self.quantity_on_hand = quantity_on_hand
```

Answer (score -2):

the *args is a sequence so you can access the items using indexing:

```
def __init__(self, *args):
        if args:       
            self.arg1 = args[0]    
            self.arg2 = args[1]    
            self.arg3 = args[2]    
            ...
```

or you can loop through all of them

```
for arg in args:
   #do assignments
```

Comment: This is more than twice as long as the code he was trying to avoid! Also, your arguments are then hard coded to be `arg1` etc.