# implicit item assignment in python objects

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to be able to assign values to class' attributes without specifying them.

What i would **like to make work**

**A)**

```py
class HoldingStuff(object):

    def __init__(self, **args):
        self.a = 1
        self.b = '1'
        self.c = 2
        self.d = '3'
        self.e = 4
        for arg in args:
            self[arg] = args[arg]

first = HoldingStuff(a=5)
second = HoldingStuff(d=2, e='2')
```

Of course i could just use a *dictionary* within the class which holds the values. There is a big downside to that however, because i can not use *code completion* for the attributes then. Which makes them hard to reuse and find. (The attributes are an extensive list of mutable parameters for a simulation.)

What **does work** (and is unpractical)

**B)**

```py
class HoldingStuff(object):

    def __init__(self, **args):
        self['a'] = 1
        self['b'] = '1'
        self['c'] = 2
        self['d'] = '3'
        self['e'] = 4
        for arg in args:
            self[arg] = args[arg]
```

What **kinda works**

**C)**

```py
class HoldingStuff(MutableMapping):

    def __init__(self, **args):
        self.a = 1
        self.b = '1'
        self.c = 2
        self.d = '3'
        self.e = 4
        for arg in args:
            self[arg] = args[arg]

    def __setitem__(self, k, v) -> None:
        if k =='a':
            self.a = v
        elif k =='b':
            self.b = v
        elif k =='c':
            self.c = v
        elif k =='d':
            self.d = v
        elif k =='e':
            self.e = v
        else:
            print(k, "Not available for class.")

    def __delitem__(self, v) -> None:
        pass

    def __getitem__(self, k) -> _VT_co:
        if k =='a':
            return self.a
        elif k =='b':
            return self.b
        elif k =='c':
            return self.c
        elif k =='d':
            return self.d
        elif k =='e':
            return self.e
        else:
            print(k, "Not available for class.")

    def __len__(self) -> int:
        return 5

    def __iter__(self):
        print("Not implemented")
```

The functions `__setitem__` and `__getitem__` seem obvious and repetitive!

**Question** 
Is there a way to reduce the source code of example **C)** to work in an implicit way of example **A)** ?

Comment: Why are you using `**args` at all? This issue never would have come up if you just wrote out your argument list normally and assigned attributes from the argument values normally.

Comment: It doesn't look like you even *want* to support arbitrary extra user-provided names, judging by those `__getitem__` and `__setitem__` methods (and arbitrary user-provided names wouldn't work with the code completion you're after either). Allowing callers to specify arbitrary keywords is the entire design purpose of `**`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [setattr](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#setattr).

```py
for name, value in args.items():
    setattr(self, name, value)
```

Comment: `ee = HoldingStuff(e='2354345')`
throws 
`ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)`

Comment: The first line should probably be `for name, value in args.items():`.

Comment: @Dion thanks worked quite nicely! I edited the answer accordingly and accepted it.

Answer (score 1):

Thank You for Your comments, which helped me find:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6760593/3707039

delivered an elegant solution

```py
class HoldingStuff(object):

    def __init__(self, **args):
        self.a = 1
        self.b = '1'
        self.c = 2
        self.d = '3'
        self.e = 4
        vars(self).update(args)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't comment because I have less than 50 reputation.
In option a,

```
class HoldingStuff(object):

    def __init__(self, **args):
        self.a = 1
        self.b = '1'
        self.c = 2
        self.d = '3'
        self.e = 4
        for arg in args:
            self[arg] = args[arg]

first = HoldingStuff(a=5)
second = HoldingStuff(d=2, e='2')
```

you have the lines:

```
for arg in args:
    self[arg] = args[arg]
```

yet you insert a string and trying to find its args' index

```
second  = HoldingStuff(d=2, e='2') #e='2'
```

I think you should try using:

```
for arg in range(len(args)):
    self[args[arg]] = args[arg]
```